# Why is there some transparency between the layers of my print?

Tags: print-quality, artillery-sidewinder-x1

When I'm printing sometimes there is some "transparency" between the layers as you can see in the picture, I'm not sure how to name the problem.

[image]

I've looked on google, somes people said It could be the nozzle that is clogged, I cleaned it and it doesn't seem clogged.

I've also seen that it could be the pressure of the spring in the extruder arm, I adjusted it.

I also checked the bed level and it looks fine.

With all thoses changes et verifications I still have the problem, not even a small improve.

Some time ago I didn't have any problem, I didn't change the cura parameters, and the problem is for every 3D files, not only this one.

In your experience what could cause this ? Did I do something wrong ?

I have a artillery sidewinder x1 which I use together with Cura. I print in PLA at 200 °C. The print bed is set to 50 °C . I use a print cooling fan at 100 %. The layer height I set to 0.16 mm, the line width 0.44 from the 0.4 mm nozzle. The Printing Speed is set to 30 mm/s for walls and 60 mm/s for infill. My retraction is 5 mm at 45 mm/s.

**EDIT 30/08/2022:**

I have tried to print the gcode given by artillery (which is the manufacturer of the 3d printer), there is two files a cube and a chick, I have the same problem except that it's only the infill.

[image]

This file is supposed to be perfect for the printer so to my understanding the problem is not from the software setting in cura, but from the printer itself.

Comment: Hello Gregory, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Your question is lacking detail and as such is hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading `<!--` and trailing `-->` afterwards. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem.

Comment: I've just added all the details you asked for, it's almost all the settings from the profiles I downloaded from the manufacturer, I think I only changed the bed temperature.

Comment: Your problem is underextrusion, no doubt. The question is what is causing this. As a few hints, please inspect he extruder (the spring or filament tensioning mechanism) and the slicer (1.75 mm diameter and flow modifier), Also be sure it isn't in volumetric extrusion.

Comment: I've disassembled the extruder parts and clean everything, there was some dust, but not a big amount. I've reassembled every thing. I've adjusted the tension of the spring, the feeling was different than before when doing it, I think last time I disassembled things, I must have badly re-assembled it. The manufacturer print looks fine now. I'm trying my files now. I'll post a new comment when I have printed more files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what was the problem here, like @0scar said I think it was the tension spring that was wrongly set, even if I had checked it before.

Also the real name of the problem was "*underextrusion*" and not "*transparency between the layers*"

Here is the steps I followed to fix it:

I disassembled the extruder by removing the screw on the side like on the picture, there is also two behind the FAN.

[image]

After that I had access to every gear that was pulling the fillament.

I cleaned everything, there was some dust but not a big quantity so I don't think I was the problem.

I also removed the spring and the spring handle. I change the tension of the spring to be as low as possible. Then I reassembled every parts.

After that I have redone the bed level and the spring tension.

Compared to the first time that I change the spring tension, this time the gear to change it felt easier, there was less resistance than last time. Even so I changed the tension to the lowest possible each time.

After doing all that I printed the manufacturer print file, It was ok, there was no longer under extrusion. Then I tried multiple file of mine, which didn't print well before all that, this time it was perfect.

**I think the real problem here was that some time ago I have disassembled the extruder and when I reassembled it I must have badly re-assembled it. Especially the spring part, since the feeling was different.**